# RegEx. \b for Cyrillic symbols

Tags: regex, pcre, cyrillic

Tell me please, what can be used instead of **\b** to highlight words in the cyrillic text?

I have a text "текст" in SQLite database column.

it's working:

```
select * from myTable where text REGEXP 'текст'
```

it's not working:

```
select * from myTable where text REGEXP '\bтекст\b'
```

Comment: [What is wrong with `\b`](https://regex101.com/r/vyjDTG/1)? Show the code.

Comment: What is your SQLite REGEXP implementation? There is no native REGEXP support in SQLite. If it is PCRE, you need `'(*UCP)\bтекст\b'`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out your SQLite `REGEXP` implementation is based on PCRE.

You may make the `\b` Unicode aware by using a `(*UCP)` PCRE verb:

```
'(*UCP)\bтекст\b'
```

There is some details about the verb at [pcrepattern man page](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html):

> Another special sequence that may appear at the start of a pattern is `(*UCP)`. This has the same effect as setting the `PCRE_UCP` option: it causes sequences such as `\d` and `\w` to use Unicode properties to determine character types, instead of recognizing only characters with codes less than 128 via a lookup table.

And later:

> Note also that `PCRE_UCP` affects `\b`, and `\B` because they are defined in terms of `\w` and `\W`. Matching these sequences is noticeably slower when `PCRE_UCP` is set.

Well, it will be slower since it has to deal with the whole Unicode table now.